# Logout button is not showing in Django Todowoo app

Tags: python, html, django

[Logout button i s not showing up in my Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJJVG.jpg)

Comment: That is because you are *not* logged in.

Comment: Thank you so much Willem I am being dumped. I thought there is some thing in my code. lol